# Using cronjob to run scrappy but not intended result

Tags: python, cron, scrapy

I am using cron job for scheduling my scrapy crawler running in interval of 12 hours.

I have created a spider which scrapes the data and stores it in csv file using `FEED_FORMAT`.

This is my content of shell file

```
#!bin/bash

cd /abc/abc/spiders
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/scrapy
export PATH
scrapy crawl abc_spider
```

Now,using `cronjob -e` I have scheduled cron to run every minute.

`* * * * * sh getdata.sh`

When I check my output using `grep CRON var/sys/syslog`,it is showing that my cron is running every minute

Although cron is running every minute,data is not getting updated in CSV file.
When I run it as `sh getdata.sh` in `CMD` it is working fine.

Please let me know your suggesstion on how fix this issue as well as how to schedule crawler using CRON I have tried many solution but this issue still persists

Comment: does your spider ends it's crawl in one minute?

Comment: Yes it does crawl in 1 minute.For verification I tried running every 2 minutes.

When I used same command in CMD,it works perfectly but when I try to put this into CRON,it does not update CSV file.

Comment: can you add those to the settings and then run the spider `LOG_STDOUT = True`
`LOG_FILE = '/project/scrapy_output.txt'` `LOG_ENABLED=True` `HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True` and then run the code once then run the cron job finally share the output of log file here

Answer (score 0):

Change the command to `sudo scrapy crawl abc_spider` and see if it works.

Comment: if this works it may indicate issues with permissions somewhere and may be a good debugging step, but generally arbitrarily throwing `sudo` in front of a command is a bad practice. It's better to find and fix the real issue rather than run every command as the root user.

Comment: True. My first guess was the permission issues. That is why I suggested trying that. If it solved the issue then you can change permissions.

Comment: I did try using sudo but there is no change in output it still persists.
Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Running spiders with its command-line process in corn job is not really recommended. you can run your spider file as good as a normal python file.
you need to do a few changes in your spider code. first import CrawlerProcess

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
# your entire code'''''''


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(YourSpiderClassName)
process.start()
```

Here, process.crawl() accepts the class name of the spider. remaining things you can keep as it is. now you will able to run your spider file with python extension. (SpiderFilename.py)

Hope this will solve your corn issue.

Comment: But I want to schedule my crawler to run once in every 12 hours.I was trying to run it every minute and cron job is getting executed but data is not getting reflected in my csv file.
I did try this but can you please guide me how do I make it run once every 12 hours?
Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: how you are feeding data into CSV, -o Data,.csv or any other method. please share some code so I can suggest the technique to feed csv based on your coding structure.

Comment: In `settings.py` file I have following settings:

`"FEED FORMAT" = "CSV"`
`"FEED URI" =  "data.csv"`

I tried using pipeline but since I want historical data,pipeline was always fetching latest data.

Comment: okay... instead of doing sets in settings.py you can set your feed format in spider itself. Like:process = CrawlerProcess({
'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
'FEED_URI': 'Filename.csv',
'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS' :['FIeld1','Field2']
})   # Here field1 and 2 are your fields to be exported in csv file.